# MapEngine.getInstance().init() discrepancy between Starter and Premium version

Tags: android, here-api

I am not sure if it is a bug between SDKs, but calling `MapEngine.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext()`, `new OnEngineInitListener() ...)` works fine from the Starter SDK. However when making the same call from the Premium SDK I get the `Context` does not match `ApplicationContext` error. I am using version 3.9.0_99 on the Premium SDK and version 3.9_18 on the Starter SDK (it also worked in version 3.8_65 of the Starter SDK as well).

Also on the examples of the SpeedLimit a class being used imports `com.here.android.mpa.common.ApplicationContext`, but in both versions listed above it is a missing class.

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/43f83c5f1f0eb86c27c906930584040598ae2cfc/speed-limit-watcher/app/src/main/java/com/here/example/speedlimit/MainActivity.java

So seems like the examples need to be updated if this class is not available anymore as well.

I am using the HERE-SDK in an android service (with the Starter SDK) and then consuming my service in another application that uses the HERE-SDK Premium version... this is my current use case (it works on paper).

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationContext class exists for Premium SDK and does not for Starter SDK.
Github samples are compatible with Premium SDK.

See more about ApplicationContext class - https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/ApplicationContext.html

Comment: After looking into this a lot I have not been able to find an answer. I defaulted o the Starter SDK. But what I really want is to build my service with the Starter SDK, and create an application that uses the Premium SDK. The samples you referred to do not really help, but I understand that the signatures are different between the SDKs for initialization and that is why it does not seem to work.